# Rsync with progress & summary report possible?

Tags: shell, rsync

I'm wondering if there's a way to invoke Rsync so that it 1) produces nice verbose output to the terminal, like what happens when you add the --progress flag and 2) creates a separate summary report (minus the verbose details) that you get when using the --stats flag.

This way I could see its status when running yet not create a monster log file.

Maybe this is not possible but I figure I'd ask.

Thanks!

Dan

Comment: I reviewed the manpage and can't come up with a solution, but you may want to play around with the new, more extensive possibilities for logging rsync 3.1 offers and see if they bring you closer to where you want to go.